# real time data updating from form

Tags: jquery, forms, real-time

I have a dynamic form that users enter receipt data. I'm trying to clone what they're inputting on a separate div that is designed to look like the receipt they're inputting. I want to display the values of the text and select elements into that separate div.

I was trying to do this in jquery. Does anyone have an example?

*edit*

The issue is that I don't know how to fetch the div id because it's being generated dynamically.

Comment: What specifically are you having an issue with? You should just be able to grab the form element value and, say, append it in a span or div, or as a table row, depending on your needs.

Comment: my issue is that the form is dynamic. It could have 50 fields or just 2. I don't know how to grab the id when it's being generated dynamically. i hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a keyup event. Assuming you set up your input field and divs like so:

```
<input type="text" id="receipt_no" />
<p>Preview:</p>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

You could do the following in jQuery:

```
$('#receipt_no').keyup(functon () {
    var preview_text = $(this).val();
    $('#preview').html(preview_text);
});
```

You can make it more complex later on by adding a common function for the receipt_no keyup and other form elements' change events (e.g. a dropdown). You just have to construct the preview_text using all the elements you need for the preview then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample:

HTML:

```
<div id="inputDiv">
<textarea></textarea>
<div>

<div id="previewDiv"><div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
  $("#inputDiv textarea").keydown(function(){
    $("#previewDiv").text($(this).value());
  });
});
```